# How to change popover arrow when target element is not in center?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tether

I have a following problem. When Popover is moved by Tether so that it remains inside a viewport, its arrow is still in center. On the image below popover is attached to the first picture (where mouse cursor is) but it looks like as if it is attached to a second picture because small arrow is still in center. Is there a way to fix that?

[image]

Here is my code

```
$('.popover-image').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'bottom',
    constraints: [{
        to: 'scrollParent',
        attachment: 'together',
        pin: true
    }],
    title: $(this).data('title'),
    content: function(){return '<img src="'+$(this).attr('src') + '" />';}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screen Shot]

Popover on image with image source in popover display

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
    $('.popover-image').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'bottom',
    constraints: [{
        to: 'scrollParent',
        attachment: 'together',
        pin: true
    }],
    title: $(this).data('title'),
    container: 'body',
    content: function(){return '<img src="'+$(this).attr('src') + '" class="img-responsive img-center" />';}
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .popover{
    max-width: 50%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
    position: relative;
  }
  .img-center {margin:0 auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-sm-4">
      <div class = "caption">
         <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="popover-image" data-trigger="hover" title="test image">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-4">
     <div class = "caption">
         <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="popover-image" data-trigger="hover"  title="test image">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-4">
     <div class = "caption">
         <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="popover-image" data-trigger="hover" title="test image">
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-sm-4">
      <div class = "caption">
         <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="popover-image" data-trigger="hover" title="test image">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-4">
     <div class = "caption">
         <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="popover-image" data-trigger="hover" title="test image">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-4">
     <div class = "caption">
         <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="popover-image" data-trigger="hover" title="test image">
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**
With Bootstrap 4

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
    $('.popover-image').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'bottom',
    constraints: [{
        to: 'scrollParent',
        attachment: 'together',
        pin: true
    }],
    title: $(this).data('title'),
    container: 'body',
    content: function(){return '<img src="'+$(this).attr('src') + '" class="img-fluid" />';}
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether-theme-arrows-dark.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <style>
  .popover{
    max-width: 100%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
   }
  .img-center {margin:0 auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example .</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top popover-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Card image cap" title="test image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example .</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top popover-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Card image cap" title="test image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example .</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top popover-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Card image cap" title="test image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example .</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top popover-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Card image cap" title="test image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example .</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top popover-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Card image cap" title="test image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example .</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top popover-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Card image cap" title="test image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice but for some reason it doesn't work with bootstrap 4. I'm trying to find the mistake but so far unsuccessful.

Comment: Updated with bootstrap 4

Comment: ...and it doesn't work. Problem as described in post. Chrome version 56